# is it possible to hack javascript interface?

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio

I'm using javascript interface on a webview. is it hackable? and if it is can it risk the client phone?

```
@JavascriptInterface
   public void SaveStatus(String divID){
   DataBaseAdapter da = new DataBaseAdapter();
   da.save(divID);
  }
```

Comment: What is your definition of "hackable"? What is your definition of "risk the client phone"? JavaScript can call that method. If you are not in control of that JavaScript, somebody could write JavaScript that calls that method, in ways and at times that you might not expect. In general, if you are using `addJavascriptInterface()`, you only want to load Web content that you create, not arbitrary Web pages.

Comment: Yes, risk the client phone. It's not your phone so who cares

Comment: [Straight from the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%2520java.lang.String)): **This is a powerful feature, but also presents a security risk** [SIC: under various OS conditions]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By exposing that function to the JavaScript environment, untrusted code running on the page can execute it. If the page is vulnerable to [JavaScript injection](https://sites.google.com/site/xssvulnerabilities/examples-of-javascript-injection-code), an attacker could exploit that to execute the function on behalf of users. Whether this is a security risk or not depends on your threat model and what this function does.